# Why can you not add vectors to this set of vectors to extend it to a base in $\mathbb{Z}_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**Question:** Given the set of vectors $\left\{(1, 2, 2), (2, 1, 1)\right\} ⊂ \mathbb{Z}^3_3$.

**Answer:** No vectors can be extended to a base.

**Remarks:**

- If you add the vector (0,0,1), the rank of the matrix is 3, so technically it would be a base.
- Moreover, a thing I noticed is (1, 2, 2) + (2, 1, 1) = (0,0,0).

Comment: This is because this vectors are linearly dependent in $\mathbb{Z}_3^3$ since, as you pointed, $(1,2,2) = -(2,1,1)$. 

To answer you first observation, if we add $(0,0,1)$ as a vector, the matrix of these vectors has rank three over the **real numbers**, not over $\mathbb{Z_3}$. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: @RUBÉNIZQUIERDOLÓPEZ So, over $\mathbb{Z}_3$, the matrix of these vectors would have rank 2 as the first two vectors are linearly dependent?

Comment: Precisely. Notice that the determinant of this matrix is $-3$ i.e. $0$ over $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: @RUBÉNIZQUIERDOLÓPEZ Right, as the rank of the matrix is less than 3, the determinant must be 0, or am I wrong?

Comment: It is true that $rank(M) = 2$, since $(1,2,2)$ and $(0,01)$ are linearly independent. $det(M) = 0$ only implies that $rank(M) < 3$ since, in general, a set of vectors (as much as the dimension) defines a basis if and only if the determinant of their matrix is nonzero in the base field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over $\mathbb{Z}_3$ the matrix of the vectors $\left\{ (1,2,2),(2,1,1) \right\} ⊂ \mathbb{Z}_3^3$ would have rank 2 as the first two vectors are linearly dependent.

If we try to incorporate the vector $(0,0,1)$, for example:

Given $
M=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} \\
$

We know that $rank(M)=2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3^3$ as $(1,2,2) = -(2,1,1)$.

Therefore, no vectors can be extended to a base.